# Deserialize JSON Array containing different types using Jackson

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON array that looks like this:

```
[
   "96.99999",
   "1",
   1378962690
]
```

Is there any way to serialize this kind of array directly, or do I need to create an Object[] array, and then cast it to the appropriate types later?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize it easily to String array.

See below example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.ArrayType;

public class JacksonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = "[\"96.99999\",\"1\",1378962690]";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ArrayType arrayType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructArrayType(String.class);

        String[] values = (String[]) mapper.readValue(json, arrayType);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
    }
}
```

After deserializing you can do with `String[] values` array anything you want.